# How does the lifetime and temperature of a black hole scale with mass in higher dimenstions?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, time, spacetime-dimensions, hawking-radiation

I've tried to find out how the lifetime and temperature of a black hole scale with mass in a universe with more then 3 spatial dimensions. I've spent a while trying to look up an answer to this question but the few papers I've found don't clearly state an answer.

Comment: Maybe this could be determined (up to a numerical factor) using dimensional analysis.